# NiFi - Use Wait/Notify for triggering GetFTP

Tags: ftp, wait, apache-nifi

I'm writing two dataflows, one is a webservice with HandleHttpRequest/Response processors, that after receiving a notification should trigger a separate flow with GetFTP to get files from an FTP directory.

I've tried to sync both using Wait/Notify processors, but GetFTP doesn't allow incoming connections so I cannot connect a Wait proc to it.

Any idea about how I can to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[`FetchFTP`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFTP/index.html) can be used in this case, as it is designed to be used in conjunction with `ListFTP`.

This is a common pattern in Apache NiFi -- there will be a `GetX` processor, and then there will be `ListX` and `FetchX` processors which are used in tandem. `ListX` scans the source directory/listing/etc. and generates a flowfile for each matching result, and sends them to `FetchX` to retrieve each item individually.

If you already know the relevant values (i.e. file names), you can provide those to the `FetchFTP` processor. If not, you'll be in the same position you are in now, because `ListFTP` is also a *source processor* and thus does not accept incoming connections. You could technically use the `Wait`/`Notify` processors to trigger a REST API invocation to start/stop the `GetFTP` processor (see [Apache NiFi REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) -- `PUT /processors/{id}`), but this is admittedly hacky.